# mongodb, truncates milliseconds in datetime after save

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I have some object with datetime field of type LocalDateTime

before save:

```
date=date=2019-12-18T09:27:20.939826
```

save and fetch from repository:

```
date=2019-12-18T09:27:20.939
```

As you can see date was truncated.

This is causing objects to not be the same in unit tests and failing assert.

What's the best way to deal with this? And How?

Edit:

config:

```
spring:
  data.mongodb:
    uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/app-db-test
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write_dates_as_timestamps: false
```

Saved datetime in mongodb:

```
ISODate("2019-12-18T09:27:20.939+0000")
```

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/bac3b67d20128e03487680b8d713195a18315d6e/src/mongo/util/time_support.h#L72  -- Can u try using this? Hope this work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

When setting a date field use:

```
LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).withNano(0)
```

In my application I introduced a central class 'Clock' from which we obtain current time:

```
Clock.time(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

This class helps with testability but also is the one place where `.withNano(0)` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date:

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of **milliseconds** since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond

> A millisecond (from milli- and second; symbol: ms) is a thousandth (0.001 or 10−3 or 1/1000) of a second.

0.939826 - is a microsecond precision.

I couldn't find any docs about whether it should be rounded up to 0.940 or truncated to 0.939. I guess it's up to driver's implementation.

Comment: From some basic testing it appears to be truncated to 0.939